# OPEN the volume mixer in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I would like to open the Windows 7 Volume Mixer upon a button being clicked, but everything I see regarding the mixer is about controlling it, when I just want to display it and let the user adjust volumes with it.

Does anybody know how to do that? Here is what I want to show:
[Windows 7 Volume Mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCEuF.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that the process name is `SndVol.exe`, you could run this:

```
Process.Start("SndVol.exe")
```